# High availability feature within DB2 on cloud

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

As per the documentation , the high availablity feature in DB2 on cloud offers an additional redundant node within the same data center ( availability zone ) only. Why cant HA be provided atleast across different AZ's within the same region?

Comment: You'd have to ask IBM, but one reason might be the latency issue with mirroring to remote locations.

Answer (score 2):

As Gilbert said, this is due to latency. The nodes are placed in the same datacenter because the HA replication is synchronous. They are kept on different power and networking pods to provide a level of isolation while still keeping them physically close.

For further physical isolation, there is the Disaster Recovery feature, where a node is added in a different datacenter altogether. This replication is asynchronous and the failovers are triggered manually by the user.

Comment: well, I am trying to compare relational db services offered across different cloud providers in terms of HA . AWS offers HA across multiple AZ's ( synchronous replication ) in a single region.  Does that make AWS a better choice than IBM cloud in terms of the HA feature.